# How can I change the icon colors, appearance, etc. at the top panel?

Tags: icons, appearance, colors

I am new to Ubuntu Linux software, and I need help changing the colors of the icons at the very top panel, where the power button, volume, bluetooth, and all those sorts of icons sit. They're kind of hard to see, and the writing is not that clear.

Detailed answers would be nice. thank you.

Comment: What version are you running? Take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/61567/how-do-i-change-the-theme for some ideas.

Answer (score 3):

Usually the top panel uses mono icons.
Right click on your desktop and go to Change desktop background.

On the theme section click on customize and choose icon.

There are two sets of mono-icon which looks nice according to color of panel.
`ubuntu-mono-dark` for dark panels and `ubuntu-mono-light` for light panels. I have attached a whole page screnshot for better understanding. Basically I am using a tweaked `ubuntu-mono-light`. The control section specifies whether you will have a dark panel or a light panel. Ubuntu has Ambience theme by default which uses Humanity Icon theme.

[image: My Light Panel based on orta theme]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the Appearance program (System > Preferences > Appearance in Ubuntu 10.10 and below), you can change the theme. If you hit the edit button, you can find a place to choose which icon set you want to use.