# How do I change icon themes?

Tags: 11.10, icons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61567/how-do-i-change-the-theme)

I like the default Ubuntu theme in Oneric, it's nice and all, but I've got other themes, icon sets, pointers, etc that I want to install. HOW DO I DO THIS? In previous versions it was a matter of right-clicking on the desktop, choosing "Change Desktop Background" from the drop-down menu and BEHOLD: all of my theme options were right there. Now, they're not. So how do I install new themes and stuff using the Unity desktop? (Not Gnome) I thought Ubuntu was supposed to be getting more user friendly. . .

Answer (score 1):

You can install `gnome-tweak-tool` and customize more than just icons (fonts, window decoration etc.).

The 'bad' thing is, it will also download some gnome-shell dependencies, but there aren't a lot of them (about 25MB in my case). (The good thing is that you can test gnome-shell, which is kinda cool ;)).

Comment: Ok cool. Gnome-shell is really cool!

Answer (score 0):

you have to install the gnome-tweak-tool package. Then, in the dash, you will find "advanced settings".

Open it and go to: Theme -> Icon theme