# Add themes in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, themes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61567/how-do-i-change-the-theme)

I just installed Ubuntu 11.10 and it seems there's only 4 themes I can choose from.
Do I have to install another program to handle themes, or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to install GNOME Tweak Tool (`sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool` in a terminal; search for it in Software Center) and search for GTK+3 themes in the Internet. Blogs like WebUpd8 have plenty of themes.