# Where are theme customizations in 11.10?

Tags: unity, 11.10, fonts, themes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61567/how-do-i-change-the-theme)

I upgraded, and now I need to tweak my fonts for the Ambiance theme - and I can't find anyplace to do it - in fact, the whole preview dialog for themes is gone - I'm not sure why they did that, but it'd be nice of them to put it back.

Answer (score 4):

Open a terminal and run the command:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

...then look for Advanced settings to run it.

http://www.installubuntulinux.com/2011/09/howto-change-system-font-sizes-in.html

Answer (score 1):

use gnome tweek and dconf editor to change themes and stuff