# Where can I get themes?

Tags: 11.10, themes, appearance

Upgrading from 11.04 to 11.10 did away with my themes, without warning me. I can't seem to find any way to customize the themes (short of going into theme files and messing with those, and I'm not quite ready to do that yet). And I can't find any themes online. I'm not enjoying Ambiance, or Radiance, or any of the ones offered by default.

Where can I find themes for Ubuntu 11.10?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the theme?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61567/how-do-i-change-the-theme)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend going to [gnome-look.org](http://gnome-look.org/) and looking in their GTK 3.x section.

Answer (score 1):

The excellent [DeviantArt crew](http://browse.deviantart.com/?order=5&q=gtk3) are now moving their old GTK+3 themes to GTK+3.2 that you'll need to use in Oneiric.

Tip - search for *GTK3* and order by the newest - you'll then see the new themes appear as they are converted.