# Why does Ubuntu Unity only have 4 themes?

Tags: unity, themes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change to a theme not listed in the Appearance screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61567/how-do-i-change-to-a-theme-not-listed-in-the-appearance-screen)

why does ubuntu unity only have 4 themes to chooes? ambiance, radiance and 2 high contrast-themes

it would be so great if there would be more themes to choose

thanx

Answer (score 1):

Check this out.
http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/02/12-new-best-gnome-shell-themes-for.html

These work in Unity perfectly
Source upubuntu.com

Comment: thankyou! but why aren't they automatically included in appearance/themes?

Comment: Those themes are for Gnome Shell, not Unity.

Comment: They work in Unity also as they are GTK3 based

Answer (score 1):

It's plenty of themes, just have a look at this great site: [Ubuntu Unity Themes](https://www.google.com/search?&q=ubuntu%20unity%20themes)

In fact, they are just 4 installed by default because they have fo fit into the 700MB live image ;)

Comment: in earlier releases it was so easy to customize themes