# Why is it not possible anymore to customize themes?

Tags: themes, ambiance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change to a theme not listed in the Appearance screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61567/how-do-i-change-to-a-theme-not-listed-in-the-appearance-screen)

in earlier releases of ubuntu, it was so easy to customize themes. you could change all the colors fast and easy. why is it not possible anymore? can't they offer this option again?

Comment: It still is easy to change color and geometry related values within the *.css style-sheets*, *.xml*, *.ini* files. However, it would be a good idea, if you edit your post and give us more information, regarding your current version of the OS (11.10/12.04) and also more information about the changes you want to make for which theme.

Comment: i use 12.04 beta

Comment: on older ubuntu-versions, you could select between many themes (clearlooks...) and easily change all the detaisl of them (colors, fonts...)