# How can I install themes on Ubuntu 12.04LTS? I know where to get but I don't know how to install them after I downloaded

Tags: themes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change to a theme not listed in the Appearance screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61567/how-do-i-change-to-a-theme-not-listed-in-the-appearance-screen)

I am new to Ubuntu. I don't know how to install softwares other than through Ubuntu software center.

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu by default comes with Ambiance theme and few other themes like Radiance etc. But these themes are not the best out there and you may want to experiment a bit with the appearance of your computer by installing a new theme but often wonder how do I install a new theme in Ubuntu 12.04. This simple tutorial will teach you to install a theme in Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity desktop environment. Follow these simple steps:

**Step 1:**

Download the theme. If it is zipped, extract it and copy the theme folder to the following location:

```
~/.themes
```

If you are using the graphical way to copy it, go to your home folder and on the top panel select View and then select Show hidden files (Ctrl+H). Now you can see .themes directory in your home directory. Copying the theme is equivalent to installing a theme.

**Step 2:**

Once you have copied the theme in correct place, the next step is to use the newly installed theme. To activate the theme we will use a wonderful tool “My Unity” which is a Unity tweaking tool and can be used for various other configuration changes such as launcher, dash, panel etc. To install My Unity use the following command in terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T):

```
sudo apt-get install myunity
```

Once you have installed the My Unity app, you can open it and move to Themes tab. Here you will see all the themes available in `~/.themes` directory. Just choose your favourite theme here.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Install the Gnome Tweak Tool / Advanced Settings for making theme selections from the software center.

   To install ubuntu tweak tool from command line:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa  
   sudo apt-get update  
   sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
   ```
2. Download and fully extract the theme packages and hold the folders on the desktop until needed

   a. (Single User) Create a .themes and .icons folder in home `/hidden` folders . Use <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open hidden folders in Nautilus.

   b. (All Users) Use `gksudo nautilus` in the terminal to open Nautilus as root and navigate to > File System `/usr/share/themes` or `/usr/share/themes` .
3. Place the folders in either Location . Use Advanced Settings to make theme selections . Logout - in may be required before themes are visible in Advanced Settings.

Comment: Please check back your answer `/usr/share/themes or /usr/share/themes`. Thanks!

Comment: themes can be found here: http://ubuntu-tweak.com/app/category/theme/