# I am not able change the themes. There is no .themes folder. And there are no my unity application and gnome application in software center

Tags: themes

Okay.. I am new to ubuntu. i have been trying to change the theme but I am not being successful.

First of all, there is no .themes folder in the home folder. And there is no My Unity application or Gnome application in software center. I tried using the tutorial given below but I have been unsuccessful because of the problems I am facing. Please help.

[How can I install themes on Ubuntu 12.04LTS? I know where to get but I don't know how to install them after I downloaded](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195897/how-can-i-install-themes-on-ubuntu-12-04lts-i-know-where-to-get-but-i-dont-kno)

Comment: gnome-tweak-tool should be in software center http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gnome-tweak-tool

Comment: Possible duplicate for http://askubuntu.com/questions/213697/how-can-i-install-themes-in-ubuntu-12-10

Comment: to see `.theme` folder you need to press ctrl+H. Those are hidden folder.

Comment: MyUnity is installed from a PPA. Go to http://www.uielinux.org/myunity/

Answer (score 1):

MyUnity is not in the Ubuntu Software Center. You must install it using apt-get. There is no .themes folder by default. You must create it and extract your themes packages there.