# How to apply this theme?

Tags: themes

How do I apply it? I don't see any instructions, and I've never applied a theme from a .zip file before. Using Ubuntu 13.04

http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/DeLorean-Dark-Stripped-Themes-3.8?content=160985

Answer (score 1):

The instructions are on the download page [here](http://killhellokitty.deviantart.com/art/DeLorean-Dark-Stripped-Themes-3-8-10042013-405087817)

> Ubuntu, Linux Mint, & Ubuntu derivatives:
>   13.04 Raring and 13.10 Saucy Add this PPA, PPA may take several hours to sink new package updates. Please be patient. copy and paste the
>   following in a terminal:
>   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:killhellokitty/themes.ppa`
>   `sudo apt-get update`
>   `sudo apt-get install delorean-dark-stripped-themes-3.8`

This will add a repository and let you install a package with the theme in it, which is probably easier/better, because you will also be able to get updates for the theme as well.

If you really want to use the .zip file, that question is answered in detail [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195897/), but essentially you just extract the contents of the theme to a directory .theme in your home directory and use the program, MyUnity to to apply the theme.