# Installing/Setting themes information very confusing

Tags: unity, 12.10, themes

I'm finding very conflicting/confusing info about how to install and change desktop themes with Unity. Where to extract files, which program to use to change themes, etc.

I'm new to ubuntu and using 12.10. All my web searches have proven this to be more difficult than anticipated.

Is there a web page with straight forward information and examples of how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/61567/how-do-i-change-to-a-theme-not-listed-in-the-appearance-screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there probably is a web page making it simple but I cannot find the one where I learned how. To install a theme in Ubuntu:

1. Download selected theme
2. Extract the theme to the .themes folder in your home folder /home/(username)/.themes
   (If you do not have the folder create it, and remember that putting a ***`.`*** in front of a folder will make it a hidden folder. So to show it on any revisiting of the folder press `Ctrl + H` to show hidden folders.)
3. Then install a tweaking tool such as MyUnity which is installable from the Ubuntu software center.
4. Then open MyUnity and navigate to the themes tab and all your themes located in the .thmes folder will be listed and you can freely choose them.

Both window themes and icon themes can be found there but to install an icon theme create a .icons folder within your home folder as you did for the themes folder.

[image]