# Where are theme pictures found

Tags: themes

This is simple, I want to download new pictures/themes for my desktop, but I don't know where to save them once they are downloaded, so that when I right-click on the desktop, those pictures show up.

Comment: For the themes, read [How do I change to a theme not listed in the Appearance screen?](http://askubuntu.com/q/61567/159545).

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on any picture and choose to set it as your wallpaper. However, to have it show up with the others when you click your desktop, place it in `/usr/share/backgrounds`