# Broken icon in unity laucher

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

My launcher icons seems broken with many snow spots?
I don't think it's a problem with the screen, because it's okay in the login screen.

Changing the icon pack does not work.

[image]

Comment: Try changing the icon pack and see if it helps. Refer to this answer on how to change them: https://askubuntu.com/a/108311/163331